# How to draw on picturebox correctly?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with standard Graphics on picturebox.Actually my picturebox image size is  x = ~5000 y= ~3000. If I use

```
Graphics gr = Picturebox1.Creategraphics();
```

Everything disappear when scrolling. Else if i use `Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(Picturebox1.Image);`

I always need to reload picture,but this is very uncomfortable.I want that Picturebox image refreshes when user "says".I found some graphics dll but they don't work.How can i draw what say above correctly?

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics.  As you found out, it's a temporary drawing.  Use the graphic provided by the paint event.  Very easy to search on this subject.

Comment: Now,Creategraphics is temporary,Graphics.FromImage is permanent.I need something average

Comment: I already told you.  Graphic object provided by the Paint event.

Comment: The `Graphics` object is a **tool** that lets you draw onto a related bitmap, including a control's surface.  The system needs to draw all the controls' surfaces at times you can't control; therefore all you want to add to those surfaces must be created from the one event that the system will call, which is the `Paint` event. Only __non-persistent__ graphics operation like displaying a dynamic rubber-band rectangle are ok with a `Graphics` object you get from `control.CreateGraphics()`. And measurements without drawing...

Comment: When you write 'average' you probably mean 'in between' or 'both'. But what you actually need is to learn the rules. Then you can play by them.

Comment: Yes.I meen something between this two things.

Comment: No such thing. Stop wishing for things that don't exist. You can combine them though, but first learn drawing from the Paint event!

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you still haven't looked in to the paint event handler, so just do this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    string fileLocation = "Get File Location";              //WHERE IS THE IMAGE LOCATED?  DON'T FORGET FILE EXTENTIONS!!

    //Graphics g = e.Graphics;                              //GRAPHICS INSTANCE
    Image img = Image.FromFile(fileLocation);               //IMAGE INSTANCE

    //  IF YOU PLACED A PICTUREBOX IN YOUR FORM.
    Size maxSize = new Size();                              //CREATE SIZE MAXIMUMS FOR THE LARGEST YOU WANT AN IMAGE TO BE
    Size imgSize = new Size();                              //FIND THE IMAGE SIZE FOR COMPARISON

    maxSize.Width = 600;                                    //SET MAX WIDTH
    maxSize.Height = 600;                                   //SET MAX HEIGHT
    imgSize.Width = img.Width;                              //FIND IMAGE WIDTH
    imgSize.Height = img.Height;                            //FIND IMAGE HEIGHT

    pbImage.MaximumSize = maxSize;                          //MAKE SURE WE DONT GO PAST OUR MAX SIZE
    pbImage.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;    //MAKE SURE THE IMAGE STRETCHES TO THE SIZE OF THE PICTURE BOX


    //HERE, WE RUN A SERIES OS CHECKS TO SEE HOW BIG TO MAKE OUR PICTURE BOX
    if (imgSize.Height < maxSize.Height && imgSize.Width < maxSize.Width)           //IF THE PICTURE IS SMALLER THAN THE MAX SIZE
        pbImage.Size = imgSize;                                                     //SET THE SIZE TO THAT OF THE PICTURE
    else if (imgSize.Height > maxSize.Height || imgSize.Width > maxSize.Width)      //IF THE WIDTH OR HEIGHT ARE LARGER THAN THE MAX
    {
        //SET HEIGHT
        if (imgSize.Height < maxSize.Height)                                        
            pbImage.Height = imgSize.Height;
        else pbImage.Height = maxSize.Height;
        //SET WIDTH
        if (imgSize.Width < maxSize.Width)
            pbImage.Width = imgSize.Width;
        else pbImage.Width = maxSize.Width;
    }
    else if (imgSize.Height > maxSize.Height && imgSize.Width > maxSize.Width)      //IF THE IMAGE IS BIGGER THAN OUR MAX
        pbImage.Size = maxSize;                                                     //MAKE IT THE SIZE OF THE MAX

    pbImage.Image = img;                                                            //PUT THE IMAGE IN THE BOX


    //  IF YOU DIDN'T - YOU SHOULD.  IT'S FAR MORE CONTROLLED
    //g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, (float)img.Width, (float)img.Height);

}
```

Hope that helps.  Obviously modify the `string` value for `fileLocation` and the max width and height to your liking.  Anything past this, do more research:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx